# How do I calculate the p-value of a one-tailed test in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have the following model: ln(MPG_{i}) = \beta _{0} + \beta *{1}WEIGHT*{i} + \beta *{1}FOREIGN*{i} + \beta *{3}FOREIGN*{i} * WEIGHT_{i} + \varepsilon_{i,j}

I want to use the **test** command to test whether the coefficient on $\beta_{3} >0.5$ in STATA.

I have used the following code and obtain this result:

test 1.foreign#c.weight = 0.5001

( 1)  1.foreign#c.weight = .5001

```
   F(  1,    70) = 4.9e+07
        Prob > F =    0.0000
```

So we reject our null, since the p-value is very small.

But the problem is that this for a two-tailed test.

My goal is to get the t-test value for this left-tailed test and then to store it. And then use the t-test to compute its p-value.

After computing the p-value, I decide whether or not to reject the null. I am certain that I would reject the null and the p-value would be quite small. Just need some help in figuring out how to code it the right way.

**EDIT:** I have tried using these commands:

```
lincom _b[forweight] - 0.5
display invttail(71, 0.5)
```

The last command spits out a value of 0. Now is this the p-value of the left-sided t-test?

Comment: Do you already know how to conduct this test and only want to learn Stata commands to do it, or is your problem perhaps also related to not knowing what test to use, how to calculate it, or how to interpret it?  Could you be specific about what kind of help you need?

Comment: @whuber It's the first part. I know the test, but would want to learn the Stata commands to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/one-sided-tests-for-coefficients/).

Here's the relevant code for testing that a coefficient is 0.5:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen ln_mpg = ln(mpg)
regress ln_mpg i.foreign##c.weight
test _b[1.foreign#c.weight]=.5 
local sign_wgt = sign(1.foreign#c.weight)
display "Ho: coef <= 0.5  p-value = " ttail(r(df_r),`sign_wgt'*sqrt(r(F)))
display "Ho: coef >= 0.5  p-value = " 1-ttail(r(df_r),`sign_wgt'*sqrt(r(F)))
```